# javascript - get items with query and match items to a user who has favorited item

Tags: javascript, push-notification, parse-platform, cloud

I am writing a script on parse.com's javascript cloud code SDK. Here is the information I have saved in my parse.com account and what I am trying to do with it.

I have a bunch of items saved in a parse class called TestItem, theses items have an objectId, item name, meal time (lunch, dinner) and a location for there columns. I also have a class called UserFavourites. In this class the objects have an objectId, item name and a pointer to the user who saved the item as a favourite.

And with this information I am trying to write a cloud code script in javascript. That will match the an item(s) to the item(s) that a user has favourited and send them a push notification saying where and what the item is and the location of the item. I have some code that will do that but this code will send a different notification for each item which could get annoying for the user here is that code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("push", function(request, response) {

var TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem");
var query = new Parse.Query(TestItem);
query.limit(1000);
query.equalTo('school', 'Union College (NY)');
query.find({
    success: function(resultsItem) {
        //console.log("Successfully retrieved " + resultsItem.length + " :1111.");
        for (var i = 0; i < resultsItem.length; i++) { 
            var object = resultsItem[i];
            var item = object.get('item');
            var school = object.get('school');
            var meal = object.get('meal');
            var meal = meal.toLowerCase();
            var diningLocation = object.get('schoolMenu');

            //var itemArray = [];
            var UserFavourite = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite");
            var queryFavourite = new Parse.Query(UserFavourite);
            queryFavourite.limit(1000);
            queryFavourite.equalTo("item", item)
            queryFavourite.equalTo("school", school)
            queryFavourite.find({
                success: function(results) {

                    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
                        var objectFav = results[i];
                        var user = objectFav.get('user');
                        var userID = user.id;
                        var realItem = objectFav.get('item');
                        console.log(objectFav.get('user'));
                        console.log(objectFav.get('item'));

                        var UserClass = Parse.Object.extend("User");
                        var queryUser = new Parse.Query(UserClass);
                        queryUser.get(userID, {
                          success: function(userResult) {
                            console.log(userResult.get('school'));        
                            console.log('install:' + userResult.get('installation').id);
                            var userInstallationId = userResult.get('installation').id;
                            var queryInstallation = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
                            queryInstallation.equalTo('objectId', userInstallationId);
                            queryInstallation.find({
                                success: function(results) {
                                    console.log('number' + results.length); 

                                        Parse.Push.send({
                                        // deviceType: [ "ios" ],
                                            where: queryInstallation,
                                            data: {
                                                alert: realItem + " is being served at " + diningLocation + " for " + meal
                                            }
                                        }, 
                                        {
                                            success: function() {
                                            // Push was successful
                                            },
                                            error: function(error) {
                                            // Handle error
                                            }
                                        }); 
                                },
                                error: function(error) {
                                    console.log('error');
                                }
                              });
                          },
                          error: function(error) {
                            console.log('error');
                          }
                        });
                     }  
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
                }
            });
         }    
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
    }
});  
});
```

As you can see it is quite long and not very nice looking, I tried to save items to an array so to avoid sending two or more notifications but couldn't get that to work.

So I started writing another script that uses promises which looks much nicer but haven't gotten it all the way right now, it can match the items to users that have an item favourited and put the objectId's of those users in an array. Here is that code.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("test", function(request, response) {

var UserFavourite = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite");
var queryFavourite = new Parse.Query(UserFavourite);

var userArray = [];
var TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem");
var query = new Parse.Query(TestItem);
query.limit(1000);
query.equalTo('school', 'Union College (NY)');
query.find().then(function(results) {
    return results;


}).then(function(results) {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) { 
        var object = results[i];
        var item = object.get('item');
        var school = object.get('school');
        var meal = object.get('meal');

        var UserFavourite = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavourite");
        var queryUser = new Parse.Query(UserFavourite);
        queryUser.equalTo("item", item);
        queryUser.equalTo("school", school);
        var prom = queryUser.find().then(function(users) {
            for (var i = 0; i < users.length; i++) {
                var user = users[i];
                var userID = user.get('user').id;
                if (userArray.indexOf(userID) === -1) {
                    userArray.push(userID);
                }
            }
            return userArray;


        });

        promises.push(prom);           
    }   
    return Parse.Promise.when.apply(Parse.Promise, promises);   

}).then(function(results) {
    console.log(userArray);
});
});
```

But now with this code I don't know where to go, I think using promises and such is the right way to go but I am now confused as once I have all the users that have an item favourited what to do, I then need to get there items that are favourited and are available in the TestItem class, this is where I am struggling.

Here is a pic of my UserFavourite class it has a pointer to the user who favorited the item as you can see, and also a user has more than one favorite.

[image]

Thanks a bunch for the help in advance.

Here is your code, and I changed a couple things.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllFavoriteItems", function (request, response) {
var TestItems = Parse.Object.extend("TestItems");
var UserFavorites = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavorites");

var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query(TestItems);
var userFavoritesQuery = new Parse.Query(UserFavorites);

testItemsQuery.equalTo('school', 'Union College (NY)');

userFavoritesQuery.include('testItems'); //This makes sure to pull all of the favorite item data instead of just the pointer object
userFavoritesQuery.matchesQuery('testItem', testItemsQuery); //This will run this second query against the TestItems
userFavoritesQuery.limit(1000); //limit results to 1000
userFavoritesQuery.ascending('userId'); //group the user id's together in your array

userFavoritesQuery.find({
        success:function(results) {
            var pushNotificationMessage = "";
            var userId = "";
            for (var i=0; i <results.length; i++) {
                if (results[i].get('userId') != userId) { 
                    if (results[i].get('userId') != "") { 
                        //TODO send push notification
                    }
                    userId = results[i].get('userId');
                    pushNotificationMessage = ""; //start a new push notification
                }

                pushNotificationMessage += results[i].get('item').get('name') + ": " + results[i].get('item').get('location') + "\n";

                //SOMEWHERE BEFORE HERE I NEED THE INSTALLATION ID OF THE USER
                //TO SEND THE PUSH TO THAT USER
                Parse.Push.send({
                // deviceType: [ "ios" ],
                    where: queryInstallation,
                    data: {
                        alert: pushNotificationMessage
                    }
                }, 
                {
                    success: function() {
                    // Push was successful
                    },
                    error: function(error) {
                    // Handle error
                    }
                });
            }
            response.success(true);
        },
        error:function(error) {
                response.error();
        }
})
});
```

Some code that might create push per user, rough outline though

```
if (i > 0) {
          if (results[i].get('user') === results[i-1].get('user')) {
            userItems.push(results[i]);
          }
          else {
            userItems.length = 0;
          }

      }
      else {
        userItems.push(results[i]);
      }
```

Not sure let me know if you understand what I'm trying to do...

So it a user has two items favourited I want it to group that into one, phrase that says what and where both items are being served

And here is code to send push

```
Parse.Push.send({
                    // deviceType: [ "ios" ],
                        where: queryInstallation,
                        data: {
                            alert: pushNotificationMessage
                        }
                    }, 
                    {
                        success: function() {
                        // Push was successful
                        },
                        error: function(error) {
                        // Handle error
                        }
                    });
```

It can also be done with then/ promises,

[image]

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve is you have a list of items and a list of favorite items, and you want the script to compile one push notification with all of the favorite items' locations. Is that right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @Maxwell that your UserFavorite should have links to both User and TestItem. This makes it possible to make your cloud-function as simple as:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllFavoriteItems", function(request, response) {

    var TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem");
    var UserFavorites = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavorites");   
    var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query(TestItem);
    var userFavoritesQuery = new Parse.Query(UserFavorites);

    testItemsQuery.equalTo('school', request.params.school);

    userFavoritesQuery.include('testItem'); 
    userFavoritesQuery.include('user'); 
    userFavoritesQuery.matchesQuery('testItem', testItemsQuery); //This will run this second query against the TestItems
    userFavoritesQuery.find().then(function(results) {
        var alerts = {};
        for(var i =0 ; i<results.length; i++ ){
            var user = results[i].get('user');
            var testItem = results[i].get('testItem');
            if(user && testItem){
                var instId = user.get('installationId');
                if(!alerts[instId]) {
                    alerts[instId] = [];
                }
                var m = results[i].get('item') + " is being served at {{diningLocation}} for " + testItem.get('meal');
              alerts[instId].push(m);
            }
        }
        response.success(alerts);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error();
    });
});
```

This is working code that you can also find in [my github repo](https://github.com/2ooom/ParseTestApp/blob/621c57c749cefa716a5ebba337fa76a5750c2714/TestApp/cloud/main.js).
You can also see the working demo [here](http://parsetestapp.azurewebsites.net/)

The idea is the same as in Maxwell's answer: to have link in `UserFavorites` class to both `User` (where installationId is located) and `TestItem` entities. I've just made it working by including `user` and `testItems` properties in query, so when the result is returned filtered by school name I already have a list of installationIds.
Here is my schema:

**User**
[image: User Schema]

**TestItem**
[image: TestItemSchema]

**UserFavorites**
[image: UserFavorites]

## Update:

In this code I added push notifications:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllFavoriteItems", function(request, response) {

    var TestItem = Parse.Object.extend("TestItem");
    var UserFavorites = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavorites");   
    var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query(TestItem);
    var userFavoritesQuery = new Parse.Query(UserFavorites);

    testItemsQuery.equalTo('school', request.params.school);

    function SendPush(installationId, msg) {
        
        var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
        query.equalTo('objectId', installationId);

        Parse.Push.send({
          where: query,
          data: {alert: msg}
        });
    } 

    userFavoritesQuery.include('testItem'); 
    userFavoritesQuery.include('user'); 
    userFavoritesQuery.matchesQuery('testItem', testItemsQuery); //This will run this second query against the TestItems
    userFavoritesQuery.find().then(function(results) {
        var groupedAlerts = {};
        // manually iterating though results to get alert strings ang group by user in groupedAlerts[installationId]
        for(var i =0 ; i<results.length; i++ ){
            var user = results[i].get('user');
            var testItem = results[i].get('testItem');
            if(user && testItem){
                var instId = user.get('installationId');
                if(!groupedAlerts[instId]) {
                    groupedAlerts[instId] = [];
                }
                var m = results[i].get('item') + " is being served at {{dining Location}} for " + testItem.get('meal');
              groupedAlerts[instId].push(m);
            }
        }
        // reformat to array and send push notifications
        var alerts = [];
        for(var key in groupedAlerts) {
            alerts.push({
                installationId: key,
                alerts: groupedAlerts[key],
            });
            // Send push notifications
            SendPush(key, groupedAlerts[key].join());
        }
        response.success(alerts);
    }, function(error) {
        response.error();
    });
});
```

I've also updated test data [in live demo](http://parsetestapp.azurewebsites.net/) (just press `Get Alerts`) or feel free to play around with test data hot it changes cloud code response. [gitnub repo](https://github.com/2ooom/ParseTestApp) is also up to up to date.

Comment: does this only send one push to each user? or if a user has multiple items favourited will it send more than one push

Comment: also I don't see where this send the push?

Comment: @spenf this example shows how you can get ids of all users who favorited TestItems with school matching to certain school. `userFavoritesQuery.find().then(function(results) {...` callback you will have access to all users and testItem records related to give school. Notifications are ommited so that you can check the behaviour. See updated answer and let me know if you need help with notifications.

Comment: its looks good except for if a user has favorited multiple items I think it will send more than one push notification, I have added some code to the bottom of my question to show what I was thinking would work, and I have added the code to send a push

Comment: @spenf what's the real-life scenario you are trying to code here?

Comment: @spenf I've tended to replicate this message from your question `realItem + " is being served at " + diningLocation + " for " + meal` and allow grouping buy user installation so that you can send one notification per such message

Comment: i can explain it in chat its kinda long, how do we get into chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61067/discussion-between-spenf-and-2ooom).

Answer (score 2):

This is based on what I understand as the problem you're trying to solve. If it's not addressing the right issue, let me know and I'll see what I can do.

Looking first at your database model, we can simplify this a bit by modifying the UserFavorites table. Starting with the initial two classes, you have a table of items and a table of users. Since a user can favorite many items and an item can be favorited by many users, we have a many-to-many relationship that exists. When this happens, we need to make a third class that points to each of the other two classes. This is where the UserFavorites table comes into play. In Parse terms, the UserFavorites table needs to have two pointers in it: one for the user and one for the item.

[image]

Once the UserFavorite table exists with it's two pointers, we can do a few things fairly easily. In your case, we have a few searching criteria:

1. each item must be at a given school
2. you want to limit your responses to the first 1000

To accomplish this you can combine two queries into one by calling matchesQuery.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getAllFavoriteItems", function (request, response) {
    var TestItems = Parse.Object.extend("TestItems");
    var UserFavorites = Parse.Object.extend("UserFavorites");

    var testItemsQuery = new Parse.Query(TestItems);
    var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
    var userFavoritesQuery = new Parse.Query(UserFavorites);

    testItemsQuery.equalTo('school', 'Union College (NY)');
    userQuery.include('Installation');

    userFavoritesQuery.include('testItems'); //This makes sure to pull all of the favorite item data instead of just the pointer object
    userFavoritesQuery.include('User'); //This makes sure to pull all of the favorite item data instead of just the pointer object
    userFavoritesQuery.matchesQuery('testItem', testItemsQuery); //This will run this second query against the TestItems
    userFavoritesQuery.matchesQuery('user', userQuery); //This will run the third query against Users, bringing the installation data along with it
    userFavoritesQuery.limit(1000); //limit results to 1000
    userFavoritesQuery.ascending('userId'); //group the user id's together in your array

    userFavoritesQuery.find({
            success:function(results) {
                    ...
            },
            error:function(error) {
                    response.error();
            }
    })
})
```

Once we get that far, then compiling the push message for each user should be a matter of straight-forward string parsing logic. For example, in the success function, one way we can extract the data we is this:

```
success:function(results) {
    var pushNotificationMessage = "";
    var userId = "";
    for (var i=0; i <results.length; i++) {
            if (results[i].get('userId') != userId) { 
                if (results[i].get('userId') != "") { 
                    //TODO send push notification
                }
                userId = results[i].get('userId');
                pushNotificationMessage = ""; //start a new push notification
            }
            pushNotificationMessage += results[i].get('item').get('name') + ": " + results[i].get('item').get('location') + "\n";
    }
    response.success(true);
}
```

I haven't tested these examples to see if they'll work, but I hope this gives you an idea of how to simplify your queries into something a little more manageable.

Comment: hey, so along with the two classes I already have (UserFavourites, TestItem) you are saying I also need a third class called FavouriteItem that has pointers to the users and his favourited Items?

Comment: Your UserFavorites class and my FavoriteItem class are the same. In your UserFavorite class, you have an object I'd to your item. Try changing that to a pointer instead.

Comment: I have added a picture of the userfavourites class with and it has a pointer to the user. Also in your code above it only queries for the current user. When this cloud function is called I want it to search all users and send each user has currently has a favourited item a push. If that makes sense?

Comment: That makes more sense. I'm out right now, but I'll look into it more when I get some time.

Comment: I still think your UserFavorites table needs to include a pointer to the item. It will simplify the table greatly as you can remove all the columns that the item pointer would already have. With that in place, you could call ascending(userId) on your query which would still give you a long array, but all the user pointers would be grouped together and make looping through it a lot simpler. Does that sound like it's heading in the right direction towards resolving your problem?

Comment: Another thing, you are searching for specific items and then trying to find the user favorites that fit those items. Parse has some functions that can help you there as well. Check this question out to see how to simplify your query by calling matchesQuery.

Comment: Forgot the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24522089/parse-ios-how-query-object-by-properties-found-in-related-pfobject

Comment: Updated my answer with my above thoughts

Comment: it looks good but if you look the code i posted first I need to the the userId and then use that to get the installationId, so I can send the push I have update code in question to show what I mean and look in the fist code block at this section `queryInstallation.equalTo('objectId', userInstallationId);`

Comment: also when I logged 'results' I got a blank array?

Comment: Make sure you're spelling UserFavorites the same way you're spelling it in your Parse DB.

Comment: in my thing its spelt userfavourtie

Comment: also in this line `userFavoritesQuery.matchesQuery('testItem', testItemsQuery);` its needs to be the testItemsQuery, but just the testItem part not the whole array of all the objects

Comment: does my previous comment make sense to you?

Comment: The last part of that comment didn't make sense. Perhaps my understanding of what you're going for is still skewed, so let me try to explain what I hoped to accomplish: using matchesQuery('testItem', testItemsQuery) would essentially give you all of the UserFavorite items who's TestItem fit that query. Is this not happening?

Comment: correct, that is not happening. The items, in TestItem and UserFavorites are saved as strings. And it gets the objects from test item, but then when I run it I get error 102: bad innerQuery

Comment: heres some explanation of the error, https://www.parse.com/questions/error-code-102-error-message-bad-type-for-inquery

Comment: Have you added a column in UserFavorites that's a pointer to TestItems? You'll need it for the inner query to work properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61003/discussion-between-maxwell-and-spenf).